# Diferencia entre crear isntancia de objeto mediante funcion constructora VS clase y constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

No entiendo la diferencia entre estos dos ejemplos, uno con clase y otro mediante una función constructora

```js
function personOne(name, age) { 
  this._name = name;   
  this._age = age;
}

var p = new personOne("David", 21);
var p2 = new personOne("Fran", 28);
console.log(p._name + ' ' + p._age);
console.log(p2._name + ' ' + p2._age);



class personTwo{ 
  constructor(name, age){
    this._name = name;
    this._age = age;
  }

}
var p = new personTwo('David', 21);
var p2 = new personTwo('Fran', 28);
console.log(p._name + ' ' + p._age);
console.log(p2._name + ' ' + p2._age);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ambos hacen exactamente lo mismo. No hay diferencias entre ambos cuando se compilan. `class` es solo una sintaxis nueva de clarar un objeto. Como dice [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> Las clases de JavaScript, introducidas en ECMAScript 2015, son
>   principalmente una sintaxis sobre la herencia existente basada en
>   prototipos de JavaScript. La sintaxis de clase no introduce un nuevo
>   modelo de herencia orientado a objetos a JavaScript.

Esto se introdujo para hacer javascript menos complejo, mas moderno y facil de aprender para las personas que se muden al lenguaje. Por ejemplo los desarrolladores de lenguajes como c# y Java les es mucho mas fácil la transición de lenguaje ya que es una sintaxis que ellos conocen.