# Pregunta sobre clases en javascript

Tags: javascript, poo, constructor

Hola buenas no entiendo Factura que es exactamente... Se que es una plantilla para todas las demas que pueda crear con new, pero Factura en si es un **objeto o una function** con metodo constructor, get y set, ya que si hago console.log me dice que es una funcion y no un objeto

```js
class Factura{ 
  constructor(numero, cliente, importe, IVA){
    this._numero = numero;
    this._cliente = cliente;
    this._importe = importe;
    this._IVA = IVA;
  }

  get total(){ 
    return this._cliente;
  }
}
```

Comment: [Habias preguntado ya eso mismo pero de otra manera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130664/diferencia-entre-crear-isntancia-de-objeto-mediante-funcion-constructora-vs-clas/130668#130668). Leiste bien mi respuesta donde explica que class es solo una nueva forma de crear un objeto pero que al compilar es lo mismo?

Comment: si la respuesta que te dieron no te funciono  seria interesnte que lo aclares en la pregunta o agregues un comentario a la respuesta que te dieron

Answer (score 2):

Las clases en javascript enrealidad son "clases genericas", ya que javascript cuando se creo no contenía o no se le habían integrado clases como tal.

Y la forma en la que creabas una clase era un tanto distinta antes de la llegada de lo que se conoce como ES6 (Ecma Script 6), este paradigma trajo muchas mas implementaciones a javascript.

Una de ellas las clases genéricas, digo genéricas porque no son clases como tal, si no una "simulación" de una clase que crearon para javascript para hacer lo que en otros lenguajes de programación se conoce como clase, a estas clases también le implementaron cosas como getters y setters que no son mas que funciones especiales con ciertas restricciones pero que te permiten cambiar u obtener de manera segura algún valor de una clase (atributos de clase).

Para entender de mejor manera las clases actuales, remontemonos a hace poco, donde una clase se veia así:

```js
//Clase y a la vez constructor
function MiObjeto(x, y, z, ancho, alto){

  //Atributos de clase
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
  this.w = ancho;
  this.h = alto;

  //Metodo de la clase
  this.haz1 = function(){

     console.log("Estoy haciendo algo!");

  }

  //Un getter de clase
  this.obtenerAlto = function(){

     return this.h;

  }

  //Un setter de clase
  this.setAlto = function(nuevoAlto){

     this.h = nuevoAlto;

  }

}

var miObjeto = new MiObjeto(0, 0, 0, 400, 400);
console.log(miObjeto.obtenerAlto());
```

Ahora hagamos la misma clase pero con ES6:

```js
//Clase, (Observa que ya no lleva parentesis).
class MiObjeto{

  //Constructor de la clase
  constructor(x, y, z, ancho, alto){
  
    //Atributos de clase
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.w = ancho;
    this.h = alto;
  
  }

  //Metodo de la clase
  haz1(){

     console.log("Estoy haciendo algo!");

  }

  //Un getter de clase
  get obtenerAlto(){

     return this.h;

  }

  //Un setter de clase
  set setAlto(nuevoAlto){

     this.h = nuevoAlto;

  }

}

const miObjeto = new MiObjeto(0, 0, 0, 400, 400);
console.log(miObjeto.obtenerAlto);//Cuando llamas a un getter la llamada no debe llevar parentesis.
```

Ahora imprimamos las dos clases en consola:

```js
class MiClase{

    constructor(){
    
    
    }

}

console.log(typeof(MiClase));
```

```js
/*Como MiClase es a su vez constructor el contenido dentro estará
 *vacio para que represente exactamente el mismo ejemplo.*/
function MiClase(){

    

}

console.log(typeof(MiClase));
```

Con esto podemos ya dar la conclusión:

Factura es una función que es implementada como una clase esto viene de las clases (funciones) anteriores a ES6, la única diferencia es la forma en la que se usan las clases, la forma en la que se construyen y los nombres que se usan para crearlas, en caso de ES5 para abajo seria function, en caso de ES6 y me imagino que para arriba mas adelante es class.

OJO!, esto solo aplica a JAVASCRIPT, la mayoria de lenguajes, tales como Java, php etc, si que tienen sus propias clases y no derivan de funciones, son clases en si como tal.

Comment: Ah por cierto, se me olvido algo, si, en javascript no existen las clases, existen son las funciones, ES6 simplemente los llama como clases, pero recuerda en javascript no hay clases, son solo funciones implementadas y nombradas como clases.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes en tu código no es ni un **function** ni un **objeto**, es una **clase** y hay que entender muy bien la diferencia.

- Un metodo es un function y es donde pones porción de código para realizar una tarea en especifico
- Un objeto es la instancia de la clase, es decir la variable con la cual llamas a la clase

-Una clase como tu lo dijiste es una plantilla la cual tiene ciertos metodos que diferentes objetos tiene en comun

Ejemplo:

```
class Perro{ 
  constructor(raza, peso, altura){
    this._raza = raza;
    this._peso = peso;
    this._altura = altura;
  }

  function ladrar(){
    console.log("LADRIDO");
  }
}
```

.-.-.-.

```
Function perrera(){
 Animal labrador = new Animal('labrador',50,1.5);
 Animal chihuahua = new Animal('chihuahua',15,1);

labrador.ladrar();
chihuahua.ladrar();
}
```

Comment: En javascript no existen las clases sino objetos y tu segundo ejemplo estás usando Java

Comment: El puso que no entiende que es la clase Factura, yo solo le di un ejemplo con su ejemplo y el otro codigo no es ni java ni js

Comment: ponte vivo :) .

Comment: si mi pregunta era, factura es una clase si que tendra propiedades comunes a todas las intancias de objeto que cree posteriormente, pero si Factura es segun Yikarus una clase, como es que puedo ponerle metodo constructor y get y set??? Porque es un objeto entonces es mi solucion, osea ES PERO NO ES UN OBJETO no? vamos que lo es porque podre crear instancias, pero en realidad es una clase que crea plantillas de objeto, cuyo objeto en si no existe, solo los creados despues con instancias, por eso dije es pero no es. Algo asi?